# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float', but it works in other cases

Tags: python, vector

This dot product of two normalized vectors work in some cases and throw this error at some cases.

```
def dotProduct(self, vec1, vec2):
    if len(vec1)!=len(vec2):
        return 0
    return sum([ x*y for x,y in zip(vec1,vec2) ])
```

Comment: Looks like sometimes `x` is a sequence and `y` is a `float`. If `x` is supposed to be a sequence, try `x*int(y)`. Can you expand your comprehension into a loop and add a `try..except` with some print debugging?

Comment: The solution worked! Thank you.